# how to change position and autowrap a footnote in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to define the position of my graph titles, footnote. How should I do it, especially for footnote, is it possible for word to auto warp?

I want some thing looks like this with:

1. title in the center;
2. footnote on the left corner;
3. date on the right corner.

[image]

My current  plot looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach, and please next time include your data. If you want multiple captions you can try using vectors. Here the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
Days<-c("-6","-6","-6","-1","-1","-1","1","6","6","6","13","13","13","16","20","20","20","24","28","28","28","44","44","44")
Event<-c("","","","","","","H","","","","","","","P","","","","H","","","","","","")
Dummy<-c("","","","","","","1","","","","","","","1","","","","1","","","","","","")
Item <-c("DIABP","PULSE","SYSBP","DIABP","PULSE","SYSBP","","DIABP","PULSE","SYSBP","DIABP","PULSE","SYSBP","","DIABP","PULSE","SYSBP","","DIABP","PULSE","SYSBP","DIABP","PULSE","SYSBP")
Result <- c("100","68","149","98","80","142","","98","88","142","110","72","160","","102","69","159","","99","82","136","97","84","144")
#Dataframe
Sample.data <- data.frame( Days, Event,Dummy, Item, Result,stringsAsFactors = F) 
Sample.data %>% mutate(ID=1) %>% mutate (Name="Jack")
#Create flags
Sample.data$Flag <- ifelse(Sample.data$Dummy==1,Sample.data$Days,NA)
#Plot
ggplot(type.convert(Sample.data)) + 
  geom_line(aes(Days, Result, group = Item, color = Item))+ 
  geom_ribbon(aes(x=Days,ymin=80,ymax=120),fill='blue',alpha=0.2)+
  geom_hline(yintercept=120)+
  geom_hline(yintercept=80)+
  geom_point(aes(x = Days, y =Dummy ))+
  geom_text(aes(x = Days, y =Dummy,label=Event,vjust = 1.75))+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=Flag),lty='dashed')+
  scale_color_discrete(breaks=unique(Sample.data$Item[Sample.data$Item!='']))+
  labs(caption = c(as.character(Sys.Date()),
                   "My caption")) + 
  ggtitle('This is plotting question')+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5),
        plot.caption = element_text(hjust=c(1, 0)))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `i`, are you in a loop?

Comment: Yes, I am using loop. That is also why I don't know how to put a data in the question. Sorry about it. This code might not work on the stay alone data plot. for looping code, without theme part and caption part, it runs well.

Comment: @Stataq You should not loop for each i, try creating a new vector and storing the values for labels then assign or use `unique(DA_AE$TRT01A[i])`

Comment: I sort of get it work now. however it looks very ugly. is it a way to autowrap the lone sentence? I uploaded the footnote that i can get so far in the post.

Comment: Try adding breaks in your caption using `\n` for example `My text is bla\nblabla and you\netc....`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221894/discussion-between-stataq-and-duck).